# How to detect if a mocha test is running in node.js?

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js

I want to make sure that in case the code is running in test mode, that it does not (accidentally) access the wrong database. What is the best way to detect if the code is currently running in test mode?

Comment: The best way to avoid that would be to mock data layer actually

Comment: Where are you running your tests that they have access to production resources?  This should be solved at the networking level.  Production databases should only accept connections from production machines.

Comment: ...it may not be the production environment. I want to make sure that tests run with the test environment. If not, I would throw an Error.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As already mentioned in comment it is bad practice to build your code aware of tests. I even can't find mentioned topic on SO and even outside.
However, I can think of ways to detect the fact of being launched in test.
For me mocha doesn't add itself to `global` scope, but adds `global.it`.
So your check may be

```
var isInTest = typeof global.it === 'function';
```

I would suggest to be sure you don't false-detect to add check for `global.sinon` and `global.chai` which you most likely used in your node.js tests.

Comment: It is now about to build code being aware of tests. I want to throw an error if someone writes a test that runs with the deployment settings. The idea is to protect some "dangerous" function from being accidentally called form a misconfigured test (like dropping a table on the production system).

Comment: Another misuse... Developer's environment is not supposed to address production configuration unless doing troubleshooting. Developer's config should be able to reach only local environment or at least stage, but not production. Nevertheless, it's all comments and advises, the answer is provided. Don't forget to let community know whether it fit your needs or is false

Comment: It's those 'troubleshooting' cases, were developers tend to forget that they are connected to the real database and run a test that potentially destroys data...

Comment: One more usecase for this is having assertions in your code that you don't mind slowing down your tests but can't afford to have in production.

Comment: A use case for the above solution: formatting debug output messages for the browser console (web app running in browser) vs terminal output (unit tests). In the former case, console.log(someObject) works better for exploring hierarchical data with browser's built-in UI, and in the latter, console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject)) is better for outputting untruncated variables.

Comment: There are cases where you want to know if it is a test, like if the app sends an email and you don't want it to send it in a test.

Comment: @ElishaSterngold one viable option is to have configs in the app. And use a separate config for tests

Comment: Alternate: `const isInTest = typeof globalThis['describe'] === 'function';`

Answer (score 5):

**Inspecting `process.argv` is a good approach in my experience.**

For instance if I `console.log(process.argv)` during a test I get the following:

```
[
  'node',
  '/usr/local/bin/gulp',
  'test',
  '--file',
  'getSSAI.test.unit.js',
  '--bail',
  '--watch'
]
```

From which you can see that gulp is being used. Using [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) makes interpretting this a whole lot easier.

I strongly agree with Kirill and in general that code shouldn't be aware of the fact that it's being tested (in your case perhaps you could pass in your db binding / connection via a constructor?), for things like logging I can see why you might want to detect this.

Comment: The only reason I need to check if the application is running under test is a check that I am not connected to a production database, because the tests clear the database. Just pure paranoia, because it should never happen -- but in 30 years in this business, I have seen a lot of things go wrong that were declared as "that will never happen".

Comment: There is a bit of a paradox here. Using code you aren't testing to make sure the test code doesn't destroy your production database. Again I'd have to re-iterate to anyone else reading this that is better to design your system so that a connection to a live database is never present. I get the premise of "that will never happen". However that same rule applies to your test for Mocha and potentially means you leave a bad design pattern in place IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option is to just use the `detect-mocha` [NPM package.

```
var detectMocha = require('detect-mocha');
if(detectMocha()) {
  // doSomethingFancy
}
```

If you don't want to do that, the [relevant code](https://github.com/AndreasPizsa/detect-mocha/blob/master/index.js#L12) is just

```
function isMochaRunning(context) {
  return ['afterEach','after','beforeEach','before','describe','it'].every(function(functionName){
    return context[functionName] instanceof Function;
})
```

Where `context` is the current `window` or `global`.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with @Joshua on his answer, he says **Inspecting process.argv is a good approach in my experience.**

So, I've written a simple detecting mocha code.

```
const _MOCHA_PATH = new RegExp('(\\\\|/)node_modules\\1mocha\\1bin\\1_mocha$');
var isMochaRunning = process.argv.findIndex(arg => _MOCHA_PATH.test(arg)) > -1;
```

Comment: Please add explanation of your code on how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

In a small project with no logging infrastructure, I use

```
if (process.env.npm_lifecycle_event !== 'test')
  console.error(e);
```

to avoid logging *expected* errors during testing, as they would interfere with test output.

Comment: `process.env.npm_lifecycle_event` is `undefined` for me when running [globally installed] mocha from Windows command line.

Comment: @SimonEast I wouldn't know why that is but three things seem likely: (1) you're not starting the node app via NPM (such as using `npm start`) but by just invoking the root script with `node`; (2) an old version of node which does not supply this variable, or (3) Node on Windows does not supply this environment variable.