# chrome is not defined - Mocha and Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I have a hard time compiling tests with `typescript`. When try to run `npm test` got

> onClicked: chrome.browserAction !== undefined ? chrome.browserAction.onClicked : undefined

**I have basic test that looks likes something:**

```
import Nightmare from "nightmare";
import * as chai from "chai";
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
import chaiString from "chai-string";
chai.use(chaiString);

import DomainDriver from "../../app/scripts/domains/driver";
const expect: any = chai.expect;
```

**The test configuration is as follows:**

```
{
  ...
  "test": "mocha --recursive --require ts-node/register --require babel-core/register tests/domains/*"
},
```

**The module code is as follows:**

```
export default {
  browserAction: {
    onClicked: chrome.browserAction !== undefined ? chrome.browserAction.onClicked : undefined,
```

The `app` directory get's compiled with webpack but it throws error with `npm test`.
The following gulp task successfully runs with webpack.

**Gulp Task**

```
gulp.task(`${PLATFORM}-webpack`, (callback) => {

    webpack(Object.create(webpackConfig), function(err, stats) {
        if(err) throw new Exception(`${PLATFORM}-webpack`, err);
        console.log(`[${PLATFORM}-webpack]`, stats.toString({
            colors: true
        }));
        callback();
    });
});
```

Am I still missing something?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by defining `chrome` as

```
const chrome = require('sinon-chrome/apps');
(global as any).chrome = chrome;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your directory the file you are looking for is in "../../app/domains/driver.ts" unless you typo-ed your directory.

Comment: That was typo in question but the error is still there

Answer (score 0):

chrome.browserAction is web-extensions code. Node.js does not know about the chrome global or web-extensions.

If you want to test web-extension code, you will need to implement a mock instance for every API you use, as sadly, nothing like it exists so far. I have started creating some mocking functions for my extension here: 
https://github.com/Lusito/forget-me-not/blob/master/test/browserMock.ts

Keep in mind, I made those to fit my needs. They are in no way complete nor do they cover all cases.

Comment: I don't have any test for `chrome.tabs` or anything related to `chrome` api. Do I still need to have this class?

Comment: Well at some point in your tests, the code shown is executed. You need to prevent execution of this code in your tests to avoid the issue. You can check if the environment is currently running tests, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183044/how-to-detect-if-a-mocha-test-is-running-in-node-js

Comment: An alternative (and a more specific check) would be to check if the global variable 'chrome' exists before using it.