# How to prevent module from being loaded in production in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

As per question title, I have a module that should be used only in test, how can I prevent it from being used in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to mock some modules in `NodeJS` for test cases.

Instead of importing conditionally, a better way would be to export real or mock object conditionally.

```
import mockModule from './mockModule';
import realModule from './realModule';

const exported = (CONDITION) ? mockModule : realModule;
export default exported;
```

Also, instead of `mockModule` you may wish to export some empty object for your use case. Something like:

```
const exported = (CONDITION)? {} : realModule;
```

`CONDITION` to check if the test is running could be different based on some environment variable or your test suite. Eg for mocha you can use:

`var isInTest = typeof global.it === 'function';`

Source: [How to detect if a mocha test is running in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183044/how-to-detect-if-a-mocha-test-is-running-in-node-js)

Also, with `require` you can import modules conditionally:

```
if (CONDITION) {
    const foo = require('foo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be all down to your build process and environment variables. I know for example that if you build using Wepback then in your webpack.config file you have the following code which you can add an exclusion to:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader", exclude: /*myModuleToExclude*/, },
    ]
}
```

Just look for the specific implementation for your specific build process.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding in "dependencies", add module in "devDependencies" section of package.json